# angular js convert string to HTML and preview it in the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, dom

I have String contains Some HTML tags 
for example :

```
$scope.string = '<div> <span> some text </span> </div>';
```

I want to convert it to html element and do some changes 
so I did That :

```
$scope.stringAfterEdit = angular.element($scope.string).find("span").addClass('newClass');
```

then I need to append my html to the page after edits .
so I tried this :

```
<div ng-bind-html="stringAfterEdit"></div>
```

but didn't work .
any idea how to do that ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: Will `angular.element($scope.string).find("span").addClass('newClass')` return a string containing valid html?

Comment: I see [object Object] in the view . no errors

Comment: @YahyaEssam It seems that you don't have a string, in that case, and I imagine you need one

Comment: so how can I convert it to string after edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by this way :
**Note** *I'm using Jquery with angularJS*

```
$scope.string = '<div> <span> some text </span> </div>';
$scope.stringAfterEdit = angular.element($scope.string);
$scope.container = angular.element('.content');
$scope.container.append($scope.stringAfterEdit);
```

and HTML

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$sce`:

```
  $scope.string = '<div> <span class="newclass"> some text </span> </div>';

  $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.string);
```

and here you cann add any classes from css. Like `newClass`

And then html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div>
```

working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JDEkkG9Wyg12LNXdmjDo?p=preview

Comment: but stringAfterEdit is not string yet

Comment: @YahyaEssam hmm, yeah ok wait a minute

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var string = '<div><span> some text </span> </div>';
  var ele = angular.element(string);
  ele.find("span").addClass('newClass');
  $scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(ele.html());
```

html:

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div>
```